# qtWebengineProcess fails to start

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I am deploying my app and getting some really cryptic messages.
I have read around and thought that it might be some issues with permissions, even apparmor. My other suspect is something missing but is unclear what, I run the application with strace and at first look nothing seems to be missing.

The build system is able to run the application but the destination machine where i am testing the install doesn't.

Here is the output:

```
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/opt/Stremio/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess
[7511:7511:0131/125813:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(182)] Check failed: ReceiveFixedMessage(fds[0], kZygoteBootMessage, sizeof(kZygoteBootMessage), &boot_pid). 
#0 0x7f1f9afa400e <unknown>
#1 0x7f1f9afb70ce <unknown>
#2 0x7f1f9b54ae33 <unknown>
#3 0x7f1f9b549b2b <unknown>
#4 0x7f1f9b54a0ce <unknown>
#5 0x7f1f9b5c1a69 <unknown>
#6 0x7f1f9b3cb373 <unknown>
#7 0x7f1f99e69d32 <unknown>
#8 0x7f1f99e6af45 <unknown>
#9 0x7f1f99e0cf31 QtWebEngineCore::BrowserContextAdapter::defaultContext()
#10 0x7f1f9f581938 QQuickWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()
#11 0x7f1f9f58769a QQuickWebEngineViewPrivate::QQuickWebEngineViewPrivate()
#12 0x7f1f9f58842b QQuickWebEngineView::QQuickWebEngineView()
#13 0x7f1f7b138460 <unknown>
#14 0x7f1f97dce68a QQmlType::create()
#15 0x7f1f97e35680 <unknown>
#16 0x7f1f97e37dfe <unknown>
#17 0x7f1f97e382ae <unknown>
#18 0x7f1f97e34be2 <unknown>
#19 0x7f1f97e35959 <unknown>
#20 0x7f1f97e36502 <unknown>
#21 0x7f1f97dbbf24 QQmlComponentPrivate::beginCreate()
#22 0x7f1f97db9619 QQmlComponent::create()
#23 0x7f1f97e2a8bb QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::_q_finishLoad()
#24 0x7f1f97e2aaa2 QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::startLoad()
#25 0x7f1f97e2aadd QQmlApplicationEngine::load()
#26 0x00000040d969 main
#27 0x7f1f96789830 __libc_start_main
#28 0x00000040dbe9 _start

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 4):

As you had noted above, i tried giving **permissions** to the project folder and all its subfolders and files. Worked like magic.

```
chmod -R <permissionsettings> <dirname>
```

For instance, i ran this:

```
chmod -R 755 <dirname>
```

Then try testing the install again.